# Some ordinal arithmetic exercises

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification, ordinals

I reckon it's easier if I don't open an extra thread for each of these small exercises. I'm trying to get a better grasp of ordinal arithmetic. If someone could please give me feedback on my solutions. :)

> 1. Every ordinal is of the form $\alpha+n$, where $\alpha$ is a limit ordinal and $n\in\omega$.
> 2. Every ordinal is of the form $\omega^\alpha\cdot m+n$, where $\alpha$ is an ordinal and $m,n\in\omega$.
> 3. If $\alpha=\omega\cdot\alpha$ (edited, previously: $\omega=\omega\cdot\alpha$), then $\alpha=\omega^\omega\cdot\beta$ for some $\beta$.
> 4. If $ \alpha=\omega^\alpha $, then $\alpha$ is uncountable.
> 5. If $\alpha>1$ and $\alpha=\alpha^\omega$, then $\alpha$ is uncountable.

1. True:

   - $\lambda$ a limit $\implies\lambda=\lambda +0$
   - $\beta=\alpha + n\implies \beta+1=\alpha+(n+1)$
2. False. Suppose $\omega^2+\omega = \omega^\alpha\cdot m + n$. Clearly need $\alpha=2$ and $m=1$ (since $\omega^2 < \omega^2 + \omega^2 = \omega^2 \cdot 2$. But $n\in\omega$, so doesn't work.
3. I need a hint for this one. I'm trying to prove it using induction but I struggle with the "if then" format. Given $\beta+1=\omega(\beta+1)$, I cannot assume $\beta=\omega\cdot\beta$ so induction seems to be pointless?
4. and 5. Both false. I think $\epsilon_0=\sup\{\omega,\omega^\omega,\omega^{\omega^\omega},\ldots\}$ is a counterexample, or do we not have $\epsilon_0^\omega = \epsilon_0$? My idea is a tower of infinitely many $\omega$ so that taking the power of one more $\omega$ cannot make a difference. I'm not sure if this is a valid ordinal, though.

Comment: Is $0$ a limit ordinal? If not, then how can $0$ be of the form $\alpha+n$ where $\alpha$ is a limit ordinal and $n\in\omega$?

Comment: 3. $\alpha=\omega^\omega\cdot\beta+\rho$ where $\rho\lt\omega^\omega.$ Assuming $\alpha=\omega\cdot\alpha$ can you show that $\rho=0$?

Comment: Yes, limit = non-successor here.

Comment: 5. Doesn't $\alpha\gt1$ imply $\alpha^\omega\gt\alpha$? Whether $\alpha$ is countable or uncountable?

Comment: @bof Ahh. $\omega\cdot\alpha = \omega\cdot\left(\omega^\omega\cdot\beta+p\right)=\omega^\omega\cdot\beta+\omega\cdot p\overset != \omega^\omega\cdot\beta + p$. So done because $\omega\cdot\gamma>\gamma$ for all $\gamma<\omega^\omega$, right?

Comment: For $0\lt\gamma\lt\omega^\omega$ but that's what you meant, yeah.

Comment: @bof What about the $\epsilon_0$ I mentioned? BrianO seemed to agree that $\epsilon_0 = \epsilon_0^\omega$ – what do you think? (See also my comment to Brian's answer)

Comment: I think that, if $\alpha\ge2,$ then $\alpha^\omega\ge2,$ and$$\alpha^\omega=\alpha^{1+\omega}=\alpha\cdot\alpha^\omega \ge \alpha\cdot2=\alpha+\alpha\gt\alpha.$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint for 3.** Ordinal multiplication is associative, so if $\omega = \omega \cdot \alpha$ and $\alpha = \omega^\omega \cdot \beta$, then 
$$\begin{align}
\omega &= \omega \cdot \alpha \\
 &= \omega \cdot (\omega^\omega \cdot \beta) \\
 &= (\omega \cdot \omega^\omega) \cdot \beta \\
 &= \omega^\omega \cdot \beta. \\
\end{align}$$
What could $\beta$ possibly be?

*PS after you revised 3.* — You've figured it out from @bof's hints in comments.

**Re 4.** Yes, $\epsilon_0$ is a counterexample. It's the least fixed point of $\alpha\mapsto \omega^\alpha$, so it's the limit (union) of the $\omega$-sequence $(0, 1, \omega, \omega^\omega, \omega^{\omega^\omega}, \cdots)$. By induction, every term of that sequence is countable; so $\epsilon_0$ is countable, as it's a countable union of countable sets.

**Re 5.** As per @bof's comments, $\alpha^\omega > \alpha$ for $\alpha > 1$, so 5. is false. (It's not true that $\epsilon_0^\omega = \epsilon_0$.)

Comment: I suppose 1 and 2 are correct then. For 3: In that case no choice of $\beta$ makes the equation true so it doesn't work. Very unfortunately, I actually meant $\alpha=\omega\cdot\alpha$ which is probably a different story. I've edited my post – sorry for that! For 4 and 5: I'm glad $\epsilon_0$ works. Just one thought: We have $\epsilon_0 + 1> \epsilon_0=\epsilon_0^\omega$. Is that not a problem? I would have thought $\alpha+1\leq\alpha^\omega$ holds for $\alpha>1$.

Comment: @akkarin Right, $\alpha\lt\alpha^2\lt\alpha^3\lt\cdots\lt\alpha^\omega$ for all $\alpha\gt1.$